# jQuery image carousel/slider/animation from JSON API

Tags: jquery, json

I have a WordPress running, and a small div with the id "api-images". This needs to be populated from a JSON that is running on a subdomain.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery("#api-images").empty();
 jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://www.mydomain.com/api/frontpage=1',
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
   handleSpecial(data);
    },
  error: function(data) {
   console.log(data);
  }
 });
});
```

I was trying to iterate through it, delaying it, then run the method again, infinitely.

```
var div = jQuery("#api-images");
jQuery.each(itemArray, function(i,v) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        div.empty();
        div.append(v);
    }, 2000);
});
```

Each v contains HTML code, like an image wrapped inside an a href. I want each image to show 2 seconds, 3 seconds, then moving on to the next. A fade-in-out would be preferable, but doesn't really matter for now.

This code does not work, and I get a "too much recursion" error. Any help?

Comment: What errors you're getting?

Comment: "too much recursion" is all it says. Even when I remove the delay.